# Google cloud - server timed out after rebooting

Tags: php, apache, centos, google-cloud-platform

I have centOS 7.* installed on Google cloud server. When I was trying to resolve permission issue for port 465, I rebooted my instance, it was not a static IP so generated a new IP. After that when I tried to hit new IP in browser, it shows **connection timed out** , what could be possible reason behind this? I have checked apache, it is active and running. Please help!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it, there were some firewall which was blocking port 80. I have stopped it by - **systemctl stop firewalld**

Don't know if it is proper solution or not, please share your thoughts. Thank you!!